# 'Bool' is not convertible to '() throws -> Bool'

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I have just started to learn RxSwift and faced with strange compile-time error.
 Code that works:

```
let createChatFlow = createChatBinding.createAction
            .withLatestFrom(createChatInputs)
            .map {  ($0.0, $0.1, $0.2.map {$0.id}) }
            .filter { !$0.2.isEmpty && $0.1?.isEmpty == false }
            .flatMapLatest { element in
                return self.conversationManager.create(chat: Chat(), with: element.0 ?? LetterImage(size: kDefaultAvatarSize, fullName: element.1 ?? kEmptyStringValue).getImage()!)
        }
```

Description:

```
createChatInputs - tuple (UIImage?, String?, [User])
```

But when i write some code inside of the last closure:

```
.flatMapLatest { element in
            var chat = Chat()
            chat.owner = AppState.current.user.id

            return self.conversationManager.create(chat: chat, with: element.0 ?? LetterImage(size: kDefaultAvatarSize, fullName: element.1 ?? kEmptyStringValue).getImage()!)
    }
```

The compiler says: `'Bool' is not convertible to '() throws -> Bool'` and point on row with `filter`. Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  `.flatMapLatest { element -> <RETURN TYPE> in ...`.
If a `flatMap` block contains just a single line, return type - isn't necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I was very confused about that error message :)